# I'm having troubles posting on my Facebook page with iMacros

Tags: facebook, macros, imacros

I'm making an iMacros macro to copy content from my website and paste it onto my site's Facebook page, but I can't make it hit the Post button (as the ID seems to change every time the page loads).

I have tried

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:"SUBMIT" ATTR=VALUE:"1"
```

but I get a runtime error "element INPUT specified by VALUE:"1" not found," and I cant click by coordinates as content of different lengths moves the Post button up or down the page.

Comment: Use Experimental recording.

Comment: I feel dumb now, haha. Thank you.

Comment: Use experimental recording. Uncheck Favor elements IDs option in settings and record the click. That should work.